# Laravel @layout issue

Tags: php, layout, laravel

I am trying to do a simple template set up with a header and footer layout that will be accessed by each page

kinda of like:

```
<html>
<body>
@layout('header')
<stuff here>
</body>
@layout('footer')
</html>
```

I have them name header.blade.php and footer.blade.php and this is inside the index.blade.php file.

But when I run it it just prints @layout('header') & @layout('footer')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question you have to provide the @yield('yieldname')